# Mosquitto Password Generation in Python

Tags: python, password-encryption, mosquitto

Is it possible to generate an encrypted Mosquitto password with python? It's for automatic generation of new users but avoiding calling mosquitto_passwd with a commandline call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import hashlib
import base64
import random

print()

chars   = b'0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

salt    = bytes([random.choice(chars) for i in range(16)])
saltB64 = base64.b64decode(salt)

passwd  = b'Hello World!'

m = hashlib.sha512()
m.update(passwd)
m.update(saltB64)
dg = m.digest()

print('$6$%s$%s' % (repr(salt)[2:-1],repr(base64.b64encode(dg))[2:-1]))
```

Comment: Please avoid `repr(x)[2:-1]` stuff and use a simple `x.decode()`